# Show bottom sheet when user presses tab icon using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a bottom sheet using `react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet` that triggers when a user presses a tab in a `React Navigation` Tab Navigator.
I want it to appear above whichever screen is currently rendered and look kind of like the below image:
[image]

I have not had any luck so far. I have created a new component for the bottom sheet, but when the user presses the corresponding tab it changes to a new page.
Is this even possible using React Navigation Tab Navigator?

Comment: Try using a custom tab button and then implement your logic of opening a bottom sheet in custom tab.

Comment: I just stumbled on that in the docs. Thanks for the confirmation @SaachiTech